# Not able to call SharePoint Rest API from an Azure AD protected Dot Net web API Project

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

I am struggling with this below case, your help can unblock me.
**Requirement:**
Execute SharePoint Rest API from a dot net core project which is secured by Azure AD.

**Details:**
I have recently created a new Dot Net Web API project which will be consumed by a React application later on. (In the Later stage access token will come coming from the React application).
I needed to protect this API project with the Azure AD app so that every API call will be authenticated properly.

**Steps I followed:**
**Step:1:** Registered an AD application and captured its information in App settings.json.(For API Permissions I have attached the screen shot)[image]
**Step 2:** For protecting this API project I have added below code in startup.cs file:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration);
```

**Step 3:** Have  this structure in App settings.json file:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": https://login.microsoftonline.com/,
    "Domain": "mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "client ID",
    "TenantId": "tenant Id",
    "Audience": "client id
    "AllowWebApiToBeAuthorizedByACL": true
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

**Step 4:** Added Authorize attribute at controller level like this:

```
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
```

**I am able to generate access token from the postman and able to access this API.**

**Actual Issue:**
In API methods I need to use SharePoint REST APIs for `GET` and `POST` operations in SharePoint Site( this action is from the backend API side)

I am getting 401 error when I use the same access token coming from `HttpContext.Request.Headers[“Authorization”];`

This made me think to generate a different token for SharePoint?
I have tried multiple different ways but had no success, not sure what is recommended approach, in this case, to be able to call SharePoint Rest APIs.
Should I need one more AD app to access SharePoint? Please advise here.

Note: Dot Net core version: 3.1, SharePoint Online

Answer (score 0):

Currently, **Azure AD App Client Secret authentication option is blocked by SharePoint Online, so it's not available to use Client Secret, it's necessary to use Certificate instead**

[image]

Please check the official document for detailed information:
[Granting access via Azure AD App-Only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread)

And here is a demo to get access token with Azure AD App Certificate in CSOM, Please refer this link:
[Calling SharePoint Online APIs using Azure AD App-Only permissions and certificate auth](https://medium.com/delaware-pro/calling-sharepoint-online-apis-using-azure-ad-app-only-permissions-and-certificate-auth-ade662e386d1)

For more details refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/283475/access-sharepoint-online-with-azuread-app-authenti.html)